# Why does it showing authenticating while I am deploying my website on vercel?

Tags: python, flask, hosting, vercel

I have created my website project with python ,flask , html and css . I want to host it , so I went to vercel . I deployed my website successfully but when is visiting it , it showing me authenticating and downloading app.py.

I want to know where I am doing mistake.